# PHP Foreach loop + PDO

Tags: php, email, pdo, foreach

I am trying to set up a email "system" for a web app I am writing. Pretty much if your role in the users table is

> 3

and your account status is

> 'Activated'

then when a new user signs up, or sends a login request all the admins will be emailed. Up until now I just hard-coded the emails, but when it comes to marketing the app, companies do not want to have to go into code to change emails. So I am trying to do it "dynamically"

My model thanks to Thomas for the most part! :

```
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE status = 'Activated' and role = 3";
        $admin_email = $this -> db -> conn_id -> prepare($sql);
        $admin_email -> execute();
        $emails = array();

        if ($admin_email)
        {
            if ($admin_email -> rowCount() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($admin_email -> fetchall() as $row)
                {
                    $emails[] = $this -> encrypt -> decode($row['email']);
                }
                return $emails;
            }
        }
    }
```

and the controller :

```
     {

        $this -> load -> model('login_model');
        $this -> load -> library('email');
        $this -> load -> library('encrypt');

        $emails = $this -> login_model -> admin_email();

        $first = $this -> input -> post('fname');
        $last = $this -> input -> post('lname');
        $email = $this -> input -> post('email');

        $this -> email -> from($email);
        $this -> email -> to($emails);
        $this -> email -> reply_to($email);
        $this -> email -> subject('' . $first . ' ' . $last . ' Account Request');
        $this -> email -> message('{unwrap}Hello this is ' . $first . ' ' . $last . ', I am requesting to be added to the staff log-in.{/unwrap}');

        if (!$this -> email -> send()) 
        {
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('email', 'Email Was Not Sent!');
            $this -> request_account();
        } else 
        {
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('login', 'Request Sent!');
            redirect('login_controller/index', 'location');
        }
    }
```

Just to dig into this more from my observations :

1. The first row returned works just fine, but for testing purposes I have two admin accounts and like I said just now, the first one only gets the email. And say if I delete the first row (the first admin) then the second one gets it. So I feel like my foreach is failing, but I do not know why or even how to correct my error(s).

If any one can show me what I am doing wrong here that would be great,

Comment: change this `$dbemail = $row['email'];` to `$dbemail= $row` and test it  again

Comment: Closing a question after the correct answer was given $this -> logic === 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function only returns a single email no matter what so you might want to try that

```
    $sql = "SELECT email from users WHERE status = 'Activated' and role = 3";
    $admin_email = $this -> db -> conn_id -> prepare($sql);
    $admin_email -> execute();

    $emails = array(); // initialize empty array

    if ($admin_email)
    {
        $encryptedEmails = $admin_email->fetchAll();
        foreach ($encryptedEmails as $row)
        {
            $emails[] = $this->encrypt->decode($row['email']); // insert the email at the end of the array
        }
    }

    return $emails;
```

Comment: Still only sent to the first row, my other admin account email did not get the notification.

Comment: interesting, if you run the SQL query separately it does return 2 emails? does the function return 2 emails in an array?

Comment: I fixed it, your going to laugh. Your answer was the closest so I'm going to +1 and check you

Comment: It had to be select *... idk why that made any difference.

Answer (score -1):

(EDIT: Deleted my first answer.... )

Maybe (i'm not sure) you shouldn't use two variables in you foreach loop.
ref:http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php

if you do :

```
       foreach ($admin_email -> fetch() as $row)
            {
                $row = $row['email'];
            }

            $email = $this -> encrypt -> decode($admin_email);
```

Your encoded emails should now be in the $admin_email array.... As the foreach processes the $admin_email array item one by one and has to return it to an array (and not to a simple string variable)


Then check if your decode function can handle arrays.

Answer (score -3):

Your admin_email function looks a bit strange

- You're calling PDO statement variable `$admin_email`, while it doesn't contain no emails. Itmakes your code pretty self-obfuscated.
- You are using try..catch operator the way it shouldn't be used.
- too much excessive `if`s
- Nothing being done to `$row['email']`
- there is some strange `decode()` function which I suspect being useless or based on some false assumptions.

So, I decided to rewrite this function more sensible way

```
function admin_email() 
{
    $sql = "SELECT email from users WHERE status = 'Activated' and role = 3";
    $stm = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    return $stm->fetchAll();
}
```

it will return an array with admin emails.

Comment: My emails are encrypted, that decode function removes the encryption and then returns the none encrypted version of that email.

Comment: I'm using a php MVC called codeigniter, when the account is created the email is encrypted, now i need to decode them to properly send to the correct email address

Comment: Updated OP. Still no results.